# How to center a php element on a html page

Tags: html

I have a php element that I would like to center. At the moment I can only have it either to the right or the left of the page.

```
<style="text-align: left;"><?php PopupContact(); ?></style>
```

Is there a simple way of getting this element to sit in the center of the page?

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP element

Comment: Would `text-align: center;` be out of the question? That or pop your php output into a div that is where you want it to be?

Comment: A PHP element? There's a new one. What **HTML elements** does `PopupContact()` produce?

Comment: please put PopupContact(); content

Comment: This is an HTML question, not php

Comment: Tried left, right so why not center?

Comment: This is such a messy post.. but there is plenty of literature on how to do this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:300px; margin:auto;"><?php PopupContact(); ?></div>
```

Where 300px is the width of your popup.

Comment: this is not fully centered, tried playing around with width but no joy. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text-align to center:

```
<style="text-align:center;"><?php PopupContact();?></style>
```

Comment: hi icyblueice - tried your suggestion but it still aligns to the left of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You can also use the stylesheet properties like

```
margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:25px; margin-top:25px; margin-right:25px;
```

You can change the size of the pixels according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code exactly for the code which you want to center using:

```
<center></center>
```

Edit code which is perhaps with

```
<?php ?>
```

As the code in header.php you might need to center only the given code which you want to be centered: Thus giving the exact to use of more `<?php` codes in the code. Just by centering near exact code by this example:

```
<center><?php 
$code = "code1 to be centered"; 
?></center>
<?php
$code2 = "code2 which is not centered";
?>
<center><?php 
$code3 = "code3 again centered"; 
?></center>
```

So perhaps you want to just put into the top of the header.php to be centered with  this example:

```
<center><?php
$code1 "code1 to be centered";
?></center>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

how to add (please wait) on time counter javascript

```js
<script language="javascript">
                        var timeout,interval
                        var threshold = <?php global $opt_themes; if($opt_themes['timer_active_']) { ?><?php echo $opt_themes['timer_fake_download']; ?>000<?php } else { ?>3000<?php } ?>;
                        var secondsleft=threshold;
                        window.onload = function()
                        {
                            startschedule();
                        }
                        function startChecking()
                        {
                            secondsleft-=1000;
                            document.querySelector(".div").innerHTML = "<span style=\"padding: 10px 30px;font-size: 40px; display:block;text-align:center;\">" + Math.abs((secondsleft/1000))+" </span>";
                            if(secondsleft == 0)
                            {
                                //document.getElementById("clickme").style.display="";
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                document.querySelector(".div").style.display="none";
                                document.querySelector(".div2").style.display="";
                            }
                        }
                        function startschedule()
                        {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            secondsleft=threshold;
                            document.querySelector(".div").innerHTML = "<span style=\"padding: 10px 30px;font-size: 40px; display:block;text-align:center;\"> " + Math.abs((secondsleft/1000))+" </span>";
                            interval = setInterval(function()
                            {
                                startChecking();
                            },1500)
                        }
                        function resetTimer()
                        {
                            startschedule();
                        }
                    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.